# Trying to remove items from an array in javascript/JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I've read several questions about this on StackOverflow, and found some solutions even, but they all seem to do the same weird thing:

I have an array (array A) of 8 names:

```
arrayA= ["person1", "person2", "person3", "person4", "person5", "person6", "person7", "person8"];
```

And I have an array (array B) of 1 name:

```
arrayB= ["person1"];
```

Now, I want to remove all names that *do not* occur in Array B, from Array A.

So I wrote a little function which loops through all items in Array A, and checks if they occur in Array B. If they do not, I remove them from Array A.

So I looked for a function to remove strings from an array (in PHP, this is all so much easier...), and I found several methods, which all give me exactly the same problem. In the example below, I chose the cleanest method, using jquery's $.grep:

```js
arrayA= ["person1", "person2", "person3", "person4", "person5", "person6", "person7", "person8"];
arrayB= ["person1"];

for (var i = 0, len = arrayA.length; i < len; i++) {
   
  if($.inArray(arrayA[i], arrayB) == -1){

    var removeName= arrayA[i];

    console.log('Removing row of: ' + removeName);

    /*
    $('tr[player=\'' + removeName + '\']').find('td')
    .wrapInner('<div style="display: block;" />')
    .parent()
    .find('td > div')
    .slideUp(700, function(){
      $(this).parent().parent().remove();
    });
    */

    arrayA= $.grep(arrayA, function(value) {
      return value != removeName;
    });
    
    console.log('arrayA now consists of: ' + arrayA);

  }

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

As you can see, it only removes the "even" items from arrayA, i.e. "person2", "person4", "person6" and "person8".

If I execute this function multiple times, the 2nd time it removes again only the "even" items (which is now "person3" and "person7"), and the third time, it removes "person5" (finally)...

Can someone please tell me what I'm not seeing?
You can see from the console log that, the first time you run it, all the "odd" items in the array, (i.e. person3, person5 and person7) are "undefined"...

Comment: What is purpose of using `for` loop? Is requirement to remove elements from original array or return new array having only elements that are within `arrayB`?

Comment: You're reindexing (or actually replacing) the array while iterating it. In other words, when you remove one, the next index becomes current, and so it gets skipped over when the loop goes to the next item.

Comment: Yeah, I guessed it must have been something like that. Could you maybe provide me with a solution to remove all items from array A that *do not* occur in array B at once, without having to loop through it and remove them one by one?

Comment: so `arrayA` should become as `["person1"]` after filtering? What is the benefit? eventually `arrayA` and `arrayB` will become equal. What's the point?

Comment: I think what you're after is to filter `arrayB` of ones that are in `arrayA`, and save that to `arrayA`... `arrayA = arrayB.filter(function(s) {
  return arrayA.includes(s)
})`

Comment: My point is: I want to perform an action for every item in Array A that is NOT in Array B (hide a table row), and THEN remove it from Array A.

Comment: But thanks anyways for pointing out to me that the indexes shift, I managed to fix it by running the for loop backwards (decreasing the value of i from array.length-1 to 0)

Comment: @LaurensSwart: I see. I didn't realize you needed to perform an action. I thought maybe B could have items that weren't also in A. Anyway, looks like you got it figured out.

Comment: @LaurensSwart _"My point is: I want to perform an action for every item in Array A that is NOT in Array B (hide a table row), and THEN remove it from Array A."_ That is omitted description of portion of requirement from Question? See http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: No it's not omitted from the question. Some people in the comments are trying to be smart by saying 'why don't you just do `arrayB = arrayA;`'... That's clearly not what I'm asking for if you look at the code I provided. You can see I'm doing something with the items that are in arrayA but not in arrayB (see code between `/* ... */`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `do..while` loop, `Array.prototype.splice()` to remove elements from an array

```js
arrayA= ["vincent"
        , "Rumpelstilzchen"
        , "LuckeR"
        , "Nordland"
        , "Siegfried"
        , "NeKrone"
        , "Carnage"
        , "tom59fr"];
arrayB= ["vincent"];

var i = 0;

do {
  if (arrayB[0] !== arrayA[i]) {
    arrayA.splice(i, 1);  
  } else {
  ++i;
  }
} while (i < arrayA.length);
delete i;

console.log(arrayA, arrayB);
```

Comment: Cool! That actually works! 
Thanks to the comment of @squint, I managed to get it working by running my for-loop backwards, to prevent shifting of the array-index which would cause it to skip every 'even' item:


`for (var i = arrayA.length-1; i >= 0; i--) {`

But this is way more elegant. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This is because when you call this:

```
arrayA= $.grep(arrayA, function(value) {
  return value != removeName;
});
```

The length of arrayA changes, thus `arrayA[k]` will move to the position of  `arrayA[k-1]` (when k>i).

So we'd better create a new array to store the filtered items and after the iteration, give its value to arrayA.

```js
arrayA= ["person1", "person2", "person3", "person4", "person5", "person6", "person7", "person8"];
arrayB= ["person1","person4"];
var arrayC=[];
for (var i = 0, len = arrayA.length; i < len; i++) {
  console.log('inArray:'+$.inArray(arrayA[i], arrayB))
  if($.inArray(arrayA[i], arrayB) != -1){
    arrayC.push(arrayA[i]);
  }
  console.log('arrayC now consists of: ' + arrayC);
}
arrayA=arrayC;
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks! I managed to prevent the shifting of indexes, by going through the array backwards (starting with `var i = arrayA.length-1`, and going down with `i--`, but your solution is cool too!